# Windows 10 bridge creates duplicate IP

Tags: pi-2, windows, internet, ethernet-port

The RPI is connected via ethernet to the laptop.

There is a bridge on the laptop between wifi connection and ethernet connection.

When I look at the pi's IP I get the same IP as the laptop.

I have no internet on RPI but on my laptop there is.

I think that there is no internet due to the fact that IP is same as laptop.
Is it supposed to be this way?

Laptop IP is 192.168.1.21.

At the picture - PI's IPs

[image: picture]

As requested at comments :

I started pi and for fue seconds i had only one ip. Picture is: [image]

After two minutes :
[image]

And as requested :
[image]

Edit :

Laptop is running windows 10.

Configured bridge by checking both wifi and ethernet network connection -> right click -> create bridge.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46832/discussion-on-question-by-hadar-s-windows-10-bridge-creates-duplicate-ip).

Answer (score 2):

According to comments under the question (shame on us, it was evolved to a chat room), you should look for a solution of the problem having title **Bridging Lan and WLan on Windows 10**.

The problem is not raspberry pi related.

Comment: @Hadar A better place for that is probably our larger sibling site [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but focus on what you've done with windows and not the Pi or it may be migrated back here out of hand.